# Change CSS Variable value in Theme Customizer Live Preview

Tags: php, jquery, theme-customizer, theme-options

I am trying to change a CSS Variable value in customizer and couldn't get live preview working using 'postMessage'. It works if I use 'refresh' option.

Can someone please have a look at the code and point me to the right direction. Thanks.

**customizer.php code**

```php
/**
 * Registers settings and controls with the Customizer.
 *
 * @param WP_Customize_Manager $wp_customize Customizer object.
 */
function mytheme_customize_register( $wp_customize ) {

    $wp_customize->add_setting(
        'primary_color',
        [
            'default'           => '#b3000e',
            'sanitize_callback' => 'sanitize_hex_color',
            'transport'         => 'postMessage',
        ]
    );

    $wp_customize->add_control(
        new WP_Customize_Color_Control(
            $wp_customize,
            'primary_color',
            [
                'label'   => __( 'Primary Color', 'mytheme' ),
                'section' => 'mytheme_color_options',
            ]
        )
    );

}
add_action( 'customize_register', 'mytheme_customize_register' );


/**
 * This will output the custom WordPress settings to the live theme's WP head.
 *
 * Used by hook: 'wp_head'
 *
 * @see add_action('wp_head',$func)
 * @since MyTheme 1.0
 */
function mytheme_customizer_header_output() {

    ?>
    <style type="text/css">

        :root {
            --primary: <?php echo esc_attr( get_theme_mod( 'primary_color', '#b3000e' ) ); ?>;
        }

    </style>
    <?php

}
add_action( 'wp_head', 'mytheme_customizer_header_output' );


/**
 * Binds JS handlers to make Theme Customizer preview reload changes asynchronously.
 */
function mytheme_customize_preview_js() {

    wp_enqueue_script( 'mytheme-customizer-preview-script', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/customizer-preview.js', [ 'jquery', 'customize-preview' ], 1.0, true );

}
add_action( 'customize_preview_init', 'mytheme_customize_preview_js' );
```

**customizer-preview.js code**

```js
( function( $ ) {

    wp.customize(
        'primary_color',
        function ( value ) {
            value.bind(
                function ( to ) {

                    //$( 'a' ).css( 'color', to );
                    $( ':root' ).css( '--primary', to );

                }
            );
        }
    );

} )( jQuery );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace

```
$( ':root' ).css( '--primary', to );
```

with

```
$( ':root' ).get(0).style.setProperty( '--primary', to );
```